# Add value in DB from Acumatica graph via Event Handler

Tags: c#, acumatica, erp

I want to add value in DB for one of my DACExtension.

```
protected void ScanHeader_Barcode_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
            
            ScanHeader row = (ScanHeader)e.Row;
            HeaderExt headerExt = row.GetExtension<HeaderExt>();
            PickPackShip.Host graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PickPackShip.Host>();
            
            SOShipment shipment = (from p in graph.Select<SOShipment>()
                            where
                            p.ShipmentNbr == row.Barcode
                            select p).FirstOrDefault();
            if (shipment != null)
            {
                SOShipmentExt shipmentExt = shipment.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>();
                cache.SetValueExt<SOShipmentExt.myField>(shipment, headerExt.MyField);
            }
}
```

I am trying like this but this is not working. My graph is not directly linked with SOShipment.
My graph is PickPackShip.Host

Answer (score 1):

Updating the field as you are only works that way on a field updated event if you are updating another field of the same cache.  Since you are setting a value on another record, just setting the value is not enough.  You also must Update the cache for that record.

```
cache.SetValueExt<SOShipmentExt.myField>(shipment, headerExt.MyField);
cache.Update(shipment);
```

This assumes that SOShipment has a cache in your graph and will be persisted when you Save.Press().

I find it interesting that you are creating an instance of a graph to select your record and then not using that graph to update the value.  If you are just initializing another copy of the same graph, then you could simplify by using *Base* if you are extending another graph or *this* if you are in your own custom graph.  Assuming you don't have any event handlers on your custom field that you want to set, I'd just add a view for SOShipment in your graph extension and update it directly.  If you want to be super proper, you likely would want to use the SOShipmentEntry graph instead, which the primary graph for SOShipment so that any future addition of event handlers would be picked up.  Then be sure to find your record in that graph and then use THAT graph to update/save your changes.  All depends on your objectives, but definitely worth thinking about.

If you have the right graph and want to update via the  PickPackShip.Host graph called graph in your code, then replace *cache* with *graph.Caches[typeof(SOShipment)]* and then be sure to *graph.Save.Press();*

If you want to use the SOShipmentEntry graph instead, the core of the update might look like this:

```
graph.Caches[typeof(SOShipment)].SetValueExt<SOShipmentExt.myField>(shipment, headerExt.MyField);
graph.Caches[typeof(SOShipment)].Update(shipment);
graph.Save.Press();  // Or graph.Caches[typeof(SOShipment)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);
```

Comment: I am creating new instance of that graph because I am not able to access Base.WMS.Shipment it is always null. I tried your way but still this is not working